# How to operate (add or substract metters) with getLatitude and getLongitude?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I need to add a marker at a place near my location. Such as:

```
new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), (mLastLocation.getLongitude()-200m))
```

...(it's an example, I don't know how to code this correctly)...

How can I add or substract metters to `mLastLocation.getLatitude()` and `mLastLocation.getLongitude()`?
Thanks.

Comment: you can use the decimal places to figure out what you need to do. http://factually.gizmodo.com/how-precise-is-one-degree-of-longitude-or-latitude-1631241162

Comment: My problem is not with the decimal, but for the formula. Is it ok using (mLastLocation.getLongitude()-x) ?

Comment: if you read the link I posted it tells you what each decimal place is equal to in distance

Comment: I'm not explaining me. I understand the relation between meters and decimal. That's not my problem. I know that I have to use "0.00233" (aprox.) instead of "200m".
My problem is: can I use directly "(mLastLocation.getLongitude()-0.00233)" and it works? How can I substract 0.00233 to my actual longitude?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), (mLastLocation.getLongitude()-200)) works fine. :)